# discrete mathematics relations question 2

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, relations

I am a little confused by this relation

R3 is a subset of Z×Z defined by (x,y) in the set R3 if and only if x>2y
is it reflexive? Symmetric? antisymmetric? or transitive?

i say its NOT reflexive because (1,2) is not in the set R3

i say it is NOT Symmetric because (1,2) is not in the set(2,1)

i say it is NOT Transitive either because if (4,1) in the set R3, (1,4) is not in the set R3

Comment: All three answers are not right, and seem to imply a lack of familiarity with the definitions of reflexive, etc. It might help you to include those definitions in the question, and also put why you think the examples you have make sense. Then others could help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R$ is not reflexive, but your reasoning is off. For any non-negative integer, we have that $x \not\gt 2x$. Hence, in those cases, $(x, x) \notin R$.

$R$ is not symmetric, since because $3 \gt 2\cdot 1 = 2$, $(3, 1) \in R$, but since $1 \not\gt 2\cdot 3 = 6, \;(1, 3) \notin R$.

However, $R$ is transitive. If $x \gt 2y$ and $y \gt 2z$, then $x \gt 2y \iff x \gt 2(2z)$, so certainly, $\frac 12 x \gt 2z \implies x \gt 2z$.

Comment: is it because since xRy and yRz then xRz

Comment: and if x was lets say, 4 and y was 2, and z was 1 then (4,1) will work

Comment: Yes, you need to prove transitivity holds for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb Z$, so that whenever $(x, y) \in R$ and $(y, z)\in R$, then $(x, z) \in R$, and not just that a particular threesome works.

Comment: @amWhy: I think this really helped! +1